# Can I give the same name to complexType and element - XSD Standards

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xsd, xsd-validation

Following is the example. Pls let me know the side effects of having same name. I am trying to create Java Object model from this XSD.

```
 <xs:element name="person" type="person"/>

        <xs:complexType name="person">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: You can do that. I would say there is not side effects: there won't be ambiguity as there are not ambiguity in referencing elements vs referencing types. If you prefer, you could also use something like *<xs:complexType name="personType">*

Comment: I am just concerned if I create Java Object model form this XSD, there won't be any issues.

Comment: I really don't know if there will be any issues related to that as I have never used Java+XSD. Maybe you should specify in your question that its related to java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fine in XML Schema terms, you can have an element and a type with the same name without ambiguity as it's obvious from the context which you are referring to at any given time.

In JAXB the *type* will map to a Java class `Person` and the element declaration will become a method on the `ObjectFactory`, with *uses* of the element mapping to `JAXBElement<Person>`. You only get an `@XmlRootElement` annotated class for elements that have an anonymous nested complexType (i.e. cases where the type can't be used for anything other than this specific root element).